# How to convert synchronously to asynchronously fetch from the internet in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, ios7, fetch

Hey guys I have this piece of code in my app that fetches data from a server. The problem as you might know is that while fetching the UI freezes. Reading around about fetching data from servers the best practice is to use async fetch, but since I don't how to do it Despite having read apple's docs, I here to ask for help on how to convert it into asynchronous fetch. My code is as follows:

```
- (void)fetchDataFromServer {

self.title = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"symbol"];
NSString *strUrl = @"http://www.aserver.com/info/";
NSString *ativo = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"symbol"];
NSString *consulta = [strUrl stringByAppendingString:ativo];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:consulta];

NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];
returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

xPathQueryDown = @"//span/meta/@content | //span[@class=' trending_down down'] | //span[@class=' trending_down down']/span | //table[@class='snapshot_table']/tr/td";
xPathQueryNone = @"//span/meta/@content | //span[@class=' trending_none none'] | //span[@class=' trending_none none']/span | //table[@class='snapshot_table']/tr/td";
xPathQueryUp = @"//span/meta/@content | //span[@class=' trending_up up'] | //span[@class=' trending_up up']/span | //table[@class='snapshot_table']/tr/td";

TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithData:returnData isXML:NO];

arrayDown = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryDown];
arrayNone = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryNone];
arrayUp   = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryUp];

if ([arrayDown count] == 9) {
    valores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayDown) {
        [valores addObject:[[element firstChild] content]];
    }

    [self cleanAndAddData];

} else if ([arrayNone count] == 9) {
    valores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayNone) {
        [valores addObject:[[element firstChild] content]];
    }

    [self cleanAndAddData];

} else if ([arrayUp count] == 9) {
    valores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayUp) {
        [valores addObject:[[element firstChild] content]];
    }

    [self cleanAndAddData];

}
}
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

instead of calling `sendSynchronousRequest` on **NSURLConnection**, you can call `sendAsynchronousRequest`. see [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a):

`sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

Comment: As I said I did read the doc from Apple but didn't understand, that's why I asked for help here. I don't know what to put within the handler on the block part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution to converting your code:

```
- (void)fetchDataFromServer
{
    self.title = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"symbol"];

    NSString *strUrl = @"http://www.aserver.com/info/";
    NSString *ativo = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"symbol"];
    NSString *consulta = [strUrl stringByAppendingString:ativo];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:consulta];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler: ^ (NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error) 
    {
        returnData = data;

        xPathQueryDown = @"//span/meta/@content | //span[@class=' trending_down down'] | //span[@class=' trending_down down']/span | //table[@class='snapshot_table']/tr/td";
        xPathQueryNone = @"//span/meta/@content | //span[@class=' trending_none none'] | //span[@class=' trending_none none']/span | //table[@class='snapshot_table']/tr/td";
        xPathQueryUp = @"//span/meta/@content | //span[@class=' trending_up up'] | //span[@class=' trending_up up']/span | //table[@class='snapshot_table']/tr/td";

        TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithData:returnData isXML:NO];

        arrayDown = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryDown];
        arrayNone = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryNone];
        arrayUp   = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryUp];

        if ([arrayDown count] == 9) {
            valores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayDown) {
                [valores addObject:[[element firstChild] content]];
            }

            [self cleanAndAddData];

        } else if ([arrayNone count] == 9) {
            valores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayNone) {
                [valores addObject:[[element firstChild] content]];
            }

            [self cleanAndAddData];

        } else if ([arrayUp count] == 9) {
            valores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayUp) {
                [valores addObject:[[element firstChild] content]];
            }

            [self cleanAndAddData];

        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will not create the best user experience. You may want to display a loading animation with a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and hide that when the data is ready.

Comment: You suggestion returns no error or warning but the fetch is not working. No data is being fetched and parsed.

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida Did you put a breakpoint inside the block to see if it's called?

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida For example, put a breakpoint on the `returnData = data;` line and see if the code is called.

Comment: returnData is returnig nil; but the variable data from the block is not nil.

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida Uhm, it is nil on that line because you have not assigned it yet. What is the value of `data`?

Comment: data __NSCFData * 120925 bytes 0x00000001120495a0

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida Great, so you have received your data. What seems to be the problem? If you try to use `returnedData` right after calling `fetchDataFromServer`, it will not work - it will be nil, because it is **asynchronous** and will only be available when the data is ready. Without specifying what you do after that with the data, we can't help you further.

Comment: after receiving the data I parse it and the put the parsed data in arrays to be used later.

Comment: Is that the code shown in the example? If so, it should work.

Comment: If you're asking if what I just said is what my code at the question does, then the answer is yes. Also before, when I used synchronous fetching it works fine.